# jar files to use <rich:columns>

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Please guide me to get the required jar files to use `<rich:columns>`. 
I have the following RichFaces jar files.

- richfaces-components-api-4.3.7.jar
- richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.jar
- richfaces-core-api-4.3.7.jar
- richfaces-core-impl-4.3.7.jar

But not able to get the `<rich:columns>`. Kindly provide the link to download the jar files.

Note: I have opened the classes in the jar files, but I am able to see only AbstractColumn.class and AbstractColumnGroup.class files. No files related to AbstractColumns.class

Answer (score 0):

`<rich:columns>` is a component from RichFaces 3.x, it is not implemented in 4.x. If you need to create columns dynamically use `<c:forEach>`.

Comment: so which one is the latest jar. 3.x or 4.x? Already i have implemented the `<c:foreach>` and it's woking fine. But the problem is it's taking too long to render the page (if the row is more than 500). is ther any way to make it fast.

Comment: Higher number means later version (usually) - 4.3.7.Final is the latest for 4.3.x, otherwise 4.5.0.Beta2 is the latest release overall.

Comment: Already we are using 4.3.4 jar. If i change to 3.x some of the components may not work. Is there any other solution to make it work?

Comment: You can't make rich:columns work in 4.x, use c:forEach instead to create columns.